# CSS flex Tab with indicator adding list elements on tab contain

Tags: html, css, flexbox, blogger

I have this CSS flex tab with indicators. I can not add ul or li contain or might be the picture contain inside the tab containing section. 
Also, want to adjust the tabcontent & indicator extending the full page from both right hands and left-hand side.

Here is the screenshot:
[image]

Tab contend is also auto adjusted, I need it in fix.

Here is Coding part: (this code is modified based on blogger template)

Fiddle code - **[fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/ocs69ss5/15/)**

```css
.protab-wrap {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
}

input[type="radio"][name="tabs"] {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}

input[type="radio"][name="tabs"]:checked+.protab-label-content label {
  color: #17D2EB;
}

input[type="radio"][name="tabs"]:checked+.protab-label-content .protab-content {
  display: block;
}

input[type="radio"][name="tabs"]:nth-of-type(1):checked~.prokslide {
  left: calc((100% / 5) * 0);
}

input[type="radio"][name="tabs"]:nth-of-type(2):checked~.prokslide {
  left: calc((100% / 5) * 1);
}

input[type="radio"][name="tabs"]:nth-of-type(3):checked~.prokslide {
  left: calc((100% / 5) * 2);
}

input[type="radio"][name="tabs"]:nth-of-type(4):checked~.prokslide {
  left: calc((100% / 5) * 3);
}

input[type="radio"][name="tabs"]:nth-of-type(5):checked~.prokslide {
  left: calc((100% / 5) * 4);
}

input[type="radio"][name="tabs"]:first-of-type:checked~.prokslide {
  left: 0;
}

label {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #1DC114;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  height: 56px;
  transition: color 0.2s ease;
  width: 100%;
}

.prokslide {
  background: #ffeb3b;
  width: calc(100% / 5);
  height: 4px;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(100% - 350px);
  transition: left 0.3s ease-out;
}

.protab-label-content {
  width: 100%;
}

.protab-label-content .protab-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  left: -25px;
  display: none;
  line-height: 130%;
  background-color: #30B932;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  h1 {
    padding: 40px 0 90px 10%;
  }
  .protab-wrap {
    width: 80%;
    margin-left: 10%;
  }
}

.buybutton {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 10px 10px;
  background: #FAB112;
  display: block;
  margin: 200px auto 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: white;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
  text-decoration: none;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 6px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.buybutton i {
  margin-right: 20px;
  transition: margin-right 0.2s ease;
}

.buybutton:hover {
  width: 134px;
  color: white;
}

.buybutton:hover i {
  margin-right: 10px;
  color: white;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .buybutton {
    margin: 400px auto 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="protab-wrap">
  <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab1" checked />
  <div class="protab-label-content" id="tab1-content">
    <label for="tab1">Tab1</label>
    <div class="protab-content">TAB 1 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis laoreet eget lectus eu congue. Nam finibus urna eget nisl aliquam, in dictum ligula feugiat. Donec mollis ligula purus, et interdum velit bibendum eget. Aliquam magna diam, tristique
      eu libero nec, sagittis finibus sapien. Cras an ex ultricies, faucibus elit sagittis, maximus nisi. Donec quis arcu sapien. Aenean risus nibh, varius sed porttitor a ornare nec leo. Sed vitae lacus in ipsum varius sagittis. Ut in quam cursus, ullamcorper
      sapien posuere, laoreet elit. Suspendisse interdum, risus ut ultricies scelerisque, nibh est commodo leo, sed tristique nisl odio et turpis. Fusce pellentesque nunc nec arcu feugiat accumsan. Praesent mauris sem, eleifend sit amet tortor in, cursus
      vehicula arcu. Curabitur convallis sit amet nunc ac feugiat. Sed at risus id diam porta pretium id vel felis. Donec nec dui id nisl hendrerit laoreet eu id odio.
      <a class="buybutton" href="https://twitter.com/mildrenben"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i>Try it now!</a><br />
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab2" />
  <div class="protab-label-content" id="tab2-content">
    <label for="tab2">Tab</label>
    <div class="protab-content">TAB 2 - Quisque egestas, purus in tempor vulputate, diam augue mollis quam, quis elementum ipsum ex a risus. Quisque sed augue porta, facilisis felis vitae, cursus mi. Nullam mollis magna eget tincidunt mollis. Sed suscipit placerat ultricies. Sed
      eget lorem et ipsum ultricies congue eu a enim. Nam quis ex nec lorem dignissim suscipit eu ut felis. Vivamus molestie felis id purus congue, vel ultrices sem molestie.
      <a class="buybutton" href="https://twitter.com/mildrenben"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i>Try it now!</a><br />
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab3" />
  <div class="protab-label-content" id="tab3-content">
    <label for="tab3">Tab3</label>
    <div class="protab-content">TAB 3 - Donec vulputate ante ac ligula vestibulum, id mollis diam commodo. Integer at consequat magna. Sed elit sem, dictum nec porttitor ac, ultrices id enim. Morbi semper eros a enim malesuada, eu finibus erat dictum. Ut vitae orci a odio sagittis
      malesuada. Cras volutpat vel lorem in tempor. Duis ultricies lectus sit amet tellus vehicula faucibus. Etiam sed leo ac erat tempor feugiat at quis ipsum. Mauris pellentesque nisl lorem, ac finibus sapien sagittis vel. Donec et lobortis est. Vestibulum
      dignissim ligula nec erat interdum, quis sollicitudin metus pretium. Vestibulum quis dui sapien. Proin commodo justo ac orci elementum molestie. Aliquam mattis orci vitae volutpat commodo.
      <a class="buybutton" href="https://twitter.com/mildrenben"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i>Try it now!</a><br />
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab4" />
  <div class="protab-label-content" id="tab4-content">
    <label for="tab4">Tab4</label>
    <div class="protab-content">TAB 4 - Quisque egestas, purus in tempor vulputate, diam augue mollis quam, quis elementum ipsum ex a risus. Quisque sed augue porta, facilisis felis vitae, cursus mi. Nullam mollis magna eget tincidunt mollis. Sed suscipit placerat ultricies. Sed
      eget lorem et ipsum ultricies congue eu a enim. Nam quis ex nec lorem dignissim suscipit eu ut felis. Vivamus molestie felis id purus congue, vel ultrices sem molestie.
      <a class="buybutton" href="https://twitter.com/mildrenben"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i>Try it now!</a><br />
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab5" />
  <div class="protab-label-content" id="tab5-content">
    <label for="tab5">Tab5</label>
    <div class="protab-content">TAB 5 - Quisque egestas, purus in tempor vulputate, diam augue mollis quam, quis elementum ipsum ex a risus. Quisque sed augue porta, facilisis felis vitae, cursus mi. Nullam mollis magna eget tincidunt mollis. Sed suscipit placerat ultricies. Sed
      eget lorem et ipsum ultricies congue eu a enim. Nam quis ex nec lorem dignissim suscipit eu ut felis. Vivamus molestie felis id purus congue, vel ultrices sem molestie.
      <a class="buybutton" href="https://twitter.com/mildrenben"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i>Try it now!</a>
      <br />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="prokslide"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using a pseudo element like `::after` you can add such indicator.

I added this rule (and gave the `label` a position, see note in CSS)

```
input[type="radio"][name="tabs"]:checked+.protab-label-content label::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 6px;
  height: 3px;  
  background: #17D2EB;
}
```

Stack snippet

```css
.protab-wrap {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
}

input[type="radio"][name="tabs"] {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}

input[type="radio"][name="tabs"]:checked+.protab-label-content label {

  position: relative;                /*  added position  */
  color: #17D2EB;
}
/*  added this new rule  */
input[type="radio"][name="tabs"]:checked+.protab-label-content label::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 6px;
  height: 3px;  
  background: #17D2EB;
}

input[type="radio"][name="tabs"]:checked+.protab-label-content .protab-content {
  display: block;
}

input[type="radio"][name="tabs"]:nth-of-type(1):checked~.prokslide {
  left: calc((100% / 5) * 0);
}

input[type="radio"][name="tabs"]:nth-of-type(2):checked~.prokslide {
  left: calc((100% / 5) * 1);
}

input[type="radio"][name="tabs"]:nth-of-type(3):checked~.prokslide {
  left: calc((100% / 5) * 2);
}

input[type="radio"][name="tabs"]:nth-of-type(4):checked~.prokslide {
  left: calc((100% / 5) * 3);
}

input[type="radio"][name="tabs"]:nth-of-type(5):checked~.prokslide {
  left: calc((100% / 5) * 4);
}

input[type="radio"][name="tabs"]:first-of-type:checked~.prokslide {
  left: 0;
}

label {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #1DC114;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  height: 56px;
  transition: color 0.2s ease;
  width: 100%;
}

.prokslide {
  background: #ffeb3b;
  width: calc(100% / 5);
  height: 4px;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(100% - 350px);
  transition: left 0.3s ease-out;
}

.protab-label-content {
  width: 100%;
}

.protab-label-content .protab-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  left: -25px;
  display: none;
  line-height: 130%;
  background-color: #30B932;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  h1 {
    padding: 40px 0 90px 10%;
  }
  .protab-wrap {
    width: 80%;
    margin-left: 10%;
  }
}

.buybutton {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 10px 10px;
  background: #FAB112;
  display: block;
  margin: 200px auto 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: white;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
  text-decoration: none;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 6px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.buybutton i {
  margin-right: 20px;
  transition: margin-right 0.2s ease;
}

.buybutton:hover {
  width: 134px;
  color: white;
}

.buybutton:hover i {
  margin-right: 10px;
  color: white;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .buybutton {
    margin: 400px auto 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="protab-wrap">
  <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab1" checked />
  <div class="protab-label-content" id="tab1-content">
    <label for="tab1">Tab1</label>
    <div class="protab-content">TAB 1 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis laoreet eget lectus eu congue. Nam finibus urna eget nisl aliquam, in dictum ligula feugiat. Donec mollis ligula purus, et interdum velit bibendum eget. Aliquam magna diam, tristique
      eu libero nec, sagittis finibus sapien. Cras an ex ultricies, faucibus elit sagittis, maximus nisi. Donec quis arcu sapien. Aenean risus nibh, varius sed porttitor a ornare nec leo. Sed vitae lacus in ipsum varius sagittis. Ut in quam cursus, ullamcorper
      sapien posuere, laoreet elit. Suspendisse interdum, risus ut ultricies scelerisque, nibh est commodo leo, sed tristique nisl odio et turpis. Fusce pellentesque nunc nec arcu feugiat accumsan. Praesent mauris sem, eleifend sit amet tortor in, cursus
      vehicula arcu. Curabitur convallis sit amet nunc ac feugiat. Sed at risus id diam porta pretium id vel felis. Donec nec dui id nisl hendrerit laoreet eu id odio.
      <a class="buybutton" href="https://twitter.com/mildrenben"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i>Try it now!</a><br />
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab2" />
  <div class="protab-label-content" id="tab2-content">
    <label for="tab2">Tab</label>
    <div class="protab-content">TAB 2 - Quisque egestas, purus in tempor vulputate, diam augue mollis quam, quis elementum ipsum ex a risus. Quisque sed augue porta, facilisis felis vitae, cursus mi. Nullam mollis magna eget tincidunt mollis. Sed suscipit placerat ultricies. Sed
      eget lorem et ipsum ultricies congue eu a enim. Nam quis ex nec lorem dignissim suscipit eu ut felis. Vivamus molestie felis id purus congue, vel ultrices sem molestie.
      <a class="buybutton" href="https://twitter.com/mildrenben"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i>Try it now!</a><br />
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab3" />
  <div class="protab-label-content" id="tab3-content">
    <label for="tab3">Tab3</label>
    <div class="protab-content">TAB 3 - Donec vulputate ante ac ligula vestibulum, id mollis diam commodo. Integer at consequat magna. Sed elit sem, dictum nec porttitor ac, ultrices id enim. Morbi semper eros a enim malesuada, eu finibus erat dictum. Ut vitae orci a odio sagittis
      malesuada. Cras volutpat vel lorem in tempor. Duis ultricies lectus sit amet tellus vehicula faucibus. Etiam sed leo ac erat tempor feugiat at quis ipsum. Mauris pellentesque nisl lorem, ac finibus sapien sagittis vel. Donec et lobortis est. Vestibulum
      dignissim ligula nec erat interdum, quis sollicitudin metus pretium. Vestibulum quis dui sapien. Proin commodo justo ac orci elementum molestie. Aliquam mattis orci vitae volutpat commodo.
      <a class="buybutton" href="https://twitter.com/mildrenben"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i>Try it now!</a><br />
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab4" />
  <div class="protab-label-content" id="tab4-content">
    <label for="tab4">Tab4</label>
    <div class="protab-content">TAB 4 - Quisque egestas, purus in tempor vulputate, diam augue mollis quam, quis elementum ipsum ex a risus. Quisque sed augue porta, facilisis felis vitae, cursus mi. Nullam mollis magna eget tincidunt mollis. Sed suscipit placerat ultricies. Sed
      eget lorem et ipsum ultricies congue eu a enim. Nam quis ex nec lorem dignissim suscipit eu ut felis. Vivamus molestie felis id purus congue, vel ultrices sem molestie.
      <a class="buybutton" href="https://twitter.com/mildrenben"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i>Try it now!</a><br />
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab5" />
  <div class="protab-label-content" id="tab5-content">
    <label for="tab5">Tab5</label>
    <div class="protab-content">TAB 5 - Quisque egestas, purus in tempor vulputate, diam augue mollis quam, quis elementum ipsum ex a risus. Quisque sed augue porta, facilisis felis vitae, cursus mi. Nullam mollis magna eget tincidunt mollis. Sed suscipit placerat ultricies. Sed
      eget lorem et ipsum ultricies congue eu a enim. Nam quis ex nec lorem dignissim suscipit eu ut felis. Vivamus molestie felis id purus congue, vel ultrices sem molestie.
      <a class="buybutton" href="https://twitter.com/mildrenben"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i>Try it now!</a>
      <br />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="prokslide"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, I applied your code, but there are few problems, the tab content is auto adjusted based with available text inside the tab content. I need fix, I tried adding height attribute inside the protab contain, but that doesn't help. Plus at the Tab1 I tried adding <ul><li> elements (bullets based text) but its not showing and looks weird. Here is the screenshot:https://image.ibb.co/dCX98Q/prob1.png Also having extra gaps

Comment: @mimi I noticed I missed the `:checked` pseudo class in the `input[type="radio"][name="tabs"]:checked+.protab-label-content label::after` rule, so I updated my answer. Still, the output your image shows is not the same as what to the code you posted render, so if you could update your question's code sample and I will have look. Drop me a note here when done, so I get a notification.

Comment: @mimi If you add `right: 0` to the `.protab-label-content .protab-content` rule it will take full width

Comment: That worked, I also removed the left: -25px; part, i was thinking instead of  such minus effect, is there any other way to expand the full tabsection, Cause in both left & right side there is still some space is empty.

Comment: Thank you, I accepted your answer. But Just little bit help with the expanding & tab content auto resize problem :( . Widget tab menu contains width are totally 100% expending just the tab contain area is not, plus its auto adjustment issue, its not in fix size

Comment: Once I added this after the drop down menu now the ul li part is not showing. Instead of adding this code via widget, let me  add this part direct with the html template code. Coming back with the result.

Comment: @mimi You are asking to many question within one post :). I have to ask you to post a new question and explain the new issue. And make sure you provide a working code snippet, as you did in this post. Code posted at _pastebin.com_ is not good since it is not runnable from there.

Comment: Hi, sorry for asking too many questions, although I deleted that last comment already ;). I solved it. :))) By adding your code inside the html template worked like charm! Thank you so much.